# Want ability to manually scroll to pull textfield above keyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

The problem is apparently when a user sees that the keyboard is blocking textfields that they want to type in, instead of hitting return, or closing the keyboard and tapping on the next field, they try to pan to the next field.  Since my content matches the size of the iPad, the scrollview doesn't automatically scroll when the user tries to pan.  Honestly, I don't want it to scroll unless the keyboard is on-screen anyway.

However, enabling scrolling on the scrollview doesn't solve the problem; it still won't respond to panning even in that case. Neither does making the viewcontroller the delegate of the scrollview and overriding the function scrollViewDidScroll. How do I get the scrollview to enable panning, particularly only when the keyboard is enabled?

Since a solution has been posted that doesn't quite work, I think I will post my keyboardWillBeShown and keyboardWillBeHidden code:

```
func keyboardWillBeShown(_ sender: Notification)
{
    self.myScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

    let info: NSDictionary = (sender as NSNotification).userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let value: NSValue = info.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    self.myScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.myScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    self.myScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.myScrollView.frame, animated: true)
    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    let activeTextFieldRect: CGRect? = activeField?.frame
    let activeTextFieldOrigin: CGPoint? = activeTextFieldRect?.origin
    if activeTextFieldOrigin != nil
    {
        if (!aRect.contains(activeTextFieldOrigin!))
        {
            let scrollpoint : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: activeField!.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height)
            self.myScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollpoint, animated: true)//.scrollRectToVisible((activeField?.frame)!, animated: true)
        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ sender: Notification)
{
    myScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    myScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    myScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get what I want.  Set myScrollView.contentSize to be as big as the screen plus the keyboard when the keyboard is shown, and reduce the size back to what it was when keyboard is hidden.  Then make the view controller a UIScrollViewDelegate, set myScrollView.delegate = self, and implement scrollViewDidScroll so that if a textfield is editing, and that textfield isn't blank, then change which text field is the first responder.  Piece of cake once you realize the trick of setting .contentSize!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Declare variables to be used

```
var originalViewCGRect: CGRect?
var originalOffset: CGPoint!
```

in `viewDidLoad` add keyboard observers

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self
        , selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear(_:))
        , name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
        , object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self
        , selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear(_:))
        , name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide
        , object: nil)
```

And finally, add these functions

```
    func keyboardWillAppear(_ notification: Foundation.Notification){
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.scrollView.frame, animated: true)
        let keyboardSize:CGSize = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
        let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
    }


    func keyboardWillDisappear(_ notification: Foundation.Notification){
        let beginFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let endFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let delta = (endFrame.origin.y - beginFrame.origin.y)
        self.view.frame = self.originalViewCGRect!
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: max(self.scrollView.contentOffset.y - delta, 0)), animated: true)
    }
```

In summary, this will adjust the content inset of the scrollview when the keyboard is shown and/or hidden.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Fixed adjustments

Comment: Hi, so thank you for taking the time to reply to my post.  I did find, however, that the code I had already solved more problems than the code you posted.  I just need the additional problem solved of being able to pan as well as hit return (if the user hits return, my code scrolls the whole thing to the upper half of the screen if necessary, so panning is the only issue I need to solve).

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding `UITextFieldDelegate` to your ViewController and add function `textFieldShouldReturn`?